# Show that $\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ is a cube root of 1?

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I know how to directly prove that complex number is one of the cube roots of 1. But the textbook solution also gives another solution as shown below,

[image: Solution Screen Shot]

However, I don't understand how it jumps to the conclusion that $\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ is a root of the quadratic equation following the two equations at the top. Thank you!

Comment: take $x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ show that $x^3=1$

Comment: Well, that's what I did. But I'm talking about another method from the textbook solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: @EzWin I think it helps a lot. Thank you!

Comment: The quadratic formula can be used here.

Comment: @Horus Right. But generally speaking, it is derived from Vieta's formula.

Answer (score 2):

Well maybe it is using Complex conjugate root theorem & Vieta's formula to say that $\alpha+ \bar{\alpha}=-1$ and $\alpha \bar{\alpha}=1$. So $\alpha$ and $\bar \alpha$ are roots of $x^2-(-1)x+1$ or $x^2+x+1$. Hence $\alpha$ divides this which divides $x^3-1$ hence $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3-1$.

Note:
$\alpha = \frac{-1+\sqrt3i}2,\;\bar\alpha=\frac{-1-\sqrt3i}2$

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember from high school how to find the solutions of $x^2 - 5x + 6 = 0$? What the trick was, was to realize that $x^2 - 5x + 6 = (x - 2)(x - 3)$.

The general form here is that $(x - a)(x - b) = x^2 - (a + b)x + ab$ and hence that $a$ and $b$ are solutions to the equation $x^2 - (a + b)x + ab = 0$.

Here we have the numbers $a = -1/2 + 1/2 \sqrt{3} i$ and $b = \overline{a} = -1/2 - 1/2 \sqrt{3}i$.

The book computes that $a + b = - 1$ so that $-(a+b) = 1$ and $ab = 1$ so that the equation to which $a$ and $b$ are solutions according to the high school trick becomes $x^2 + 1x + 1 = 0$.

Of course, when you were actually in high school you would be given the equation and asked to find solution instead of the other way around, but the reasing is more or less the same.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question explicitly asks to explain how to get to the quadratic equation, not to explain why the equation $(-1/2 + 1/2 \sqrt{3} i)^3 = 1$ because the poster already understands that latter fact.

Comment: O wait, maybe it was because of the wrong minus sign? I corrected it now

Comment: I think you're right, though my high school (outside u.s) didn't teach us that formula. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $2y=-1+\sqrt3i$

$\implies(2y+1)^2=(\sqrt3i)^2$

$\iff y^2+y+1=0\implies y^3-1=(y-1)(y^2+y+1)=?$

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure about credibility of the following but since we have to prove:
${-1+\sqrt3{i}\over2}={\sqrt[3]{1}}$

${(-1+\sqrt3{i})^3\over8}=1$

$\impliedby{(-1+\sqrt3{i})^3}=8$

$\impliedby-1+3\sqrt3i+9-3\sqrt3i=8$

$\impliedby3\sqrt3i-3\sqrt3i=0$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

take $x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ show that $x^3=1$
$$x=\frac12(-1+\sqrt{3}i)\\x^3=\frac{1}{8}((-1)^3+(\sqrt{3}i)^3+3(\sqrt{3}i)(-1)(-1+\sqrt{3}i))=\\
\frac18 (-1-3\sqrt3i+3\sqrt3i-9i^2)=\\\frac18(-1-9i^2)=\\\frac18(-1+9)=\\1$$
other method
$$x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2-x+1)=0\\x=1\\x^2-x+1=0\\\to (x-\frac12)^2-(\frac14)+1=0\\(x-\frac12)^2=-(\frac34)\\(x-\frac12)=\pm\frac {\sqrt{-3}}{2}\\
(x-\frac12)=\pm\frac {\sqrt{3}i}{2}\\
x=\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac {\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$